# Create regex pattern for a specified String

Tags: android, regex, string, pattern-matching

I want to check if a String has a specified structure. I think regex would be the best way to test the String, but I have never used regex before and have sadly no clue how it works. I watched some explanations on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find a good explanation how the regex pattern was created.

My String gets returned from a DataMatrix scanner. For example

```
 String contained = "~ak4,0000D"
```

Now I want to test this String, if it matches the pattern from the regex.

The String starts everytime with the "~".

After this, two lower cased charactes follow in this example "ak".

After this, there follows a six character long value "4,0000". Main problem here, because the comma can sit anywhere in this value, but the comma must be contained in it. For example it can be ",16000" or "150,00" or "2,8000".

At the last position there must be one of this characters A B C D E F G H J K L M in uppercase contained.

I hope some of you guys can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex would be `~[a-z]{2}(?=[\d\,]{6})((\d)*\,(\d)*)[A-H|J-M]{1}$` You can create and test expressions [here](http://www.regexr.com/)

```
boolean isMatch(String STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_MATCH)
{
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(YOUR_REGEX_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_MATCH);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Comment: `[A-M]` doesn't match OP's request. `A B C D E F G H J K L M`

Comment: `[\d|\,]` matches pipes also and  `[\d|\,]{6}` matches also 6 digits only .

Comment: The "[\d,]{6}" subpattern is incorrect, as it allows any number of ',' characters among the six, whereas the requirement is to match exactly one.

Comment: It would give OP the basic idea about regular expressions, too.

Comment: Seems too work very nice, gonna test this, by scanning some more Data Matrix

Comment: @JohnBollinger Edited my answer. Regex now checks that subpattern contains exact 1 comma

Answer (score 1):

One thing you need to know about regular expressions are that they are a *family* of things, not one specific thing.  There are rather a lot of distinct but similar regular expression languages, and the facilities supporting them vary from programming language to programming language.

Here is a regex pattern that will work in most regex languages to match your strings:

```
"^~[a-z][a-z]((,[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9],))[A-HJ-M]$"
```

The '^' anchors the pattern to the beginning of the string, and the '$' anchors it to the end, so that the pattern must match the whole string as opposed to a substring.  Characters enclosed in square brackets represent "character classes" matching exactly one character from among a set, with the two characters separated by a '-' representing a range of characters.  The '|' separates alternatives, and parentheses serve to group subpatterns.  For some regex engines, the parentheses and '\' symbols need to be escaped via a preceeding '\' character to have these special meanings instead of representing themselves.

A more featureful regex language can allow that to be greatly simplified; for example:

```
"^~[a-z]{2}[0-9,]{6}(?<=[a-z][0-9]*,[0-9]*)[A-HJ-M]$"
```

The quantifiers "{2}" and "{6}" designate that the preceding subpattern must match exactly the specified number of times (instead of once), and the quantifier "*" designates that the preceding subpattern may match any number of times, including zero.  Additionally, the "(?<= ...)" is a zero-length look-behind assertion, which tests whether the previous characters of the input match the given sub-pattern (in addition to having already matched the preceding sub-pattern); the characters must also match the subsequent sub-pattern (which does consume them).  The '.' metacharacter and '*' quantifier are supported in pretty much all regex languages, but assertions and curly-brace quantifiers are less widely supported. Java's and Perl's regular expression languages will both understand this pattern, however.

Comment: @RaviVadera, fair enough.  Fixed by swapping the contents of the assertion and the following sub-pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation of regular expressions. I really like your effort you put into that. It made me understand regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a positive lookahead based regex like below.

```
 System.out.println("~ak4,0000D".matches("~[a-z]{2}(?=\\d*,\\d*.$)[\\d,]{6}[A-HJ-M]"));
 System.out.println("~fk,10000D".matches("~[a-z]{2}(?=\\d*,\\d*.$)[\\d,]{6}[A-HJ-M]"));
 System.out.println("~jk400,00D".matches("~[a-z]{2}(?=\\d*,\\d*.$)[\\d,]{6}[A-HJ-M]"));
 System.out.println("~ak4,0000D".matches("~[a-z]{2}(?=\\d*,\\d*.$)[\\d,]{6}[A-HJ-M]"));
 System.out.println("~fk10000,D".matches("~[a-z]{2}(?=\\d*,\\d*.$)[\\d,]{6}[A-HJ-M]"));
 System.out.println("~jk400,00I".matches("~[a-z]{2}(?=\\d*,\\d*.$)[\\d,]{6}[A-HJ-M]"));
 System.out.println("~ak40000,Z".matches("~[a-z]{2}(?=\\d*,\\d*.$)[\\d,]{6}[A-HJ-M]"));
 System.out.println("~fky,10000D".matches("~[a-z]{2}(?=\\d*,\\d*.$)[\\d,]{6}[A-HJ-M]"));
 System.out.println("~,jk40000D".matches("~[a-z]{2}(?=\\d*,\\d*.$)[\\d,]{6}[A-HJ-M]"));
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
```

Comment: You don't *need* a look-ahead assertion for this, but it sure is convenient to use one.

Comment: could you provide an answer without lookarounds.

Comment: I did provide it.  Before you posted your answer, even.  Look at my answer.  You don't even need to depend on enumerated quantifiers, which, by the way, some regex engines don't handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
~[a-z]{2}[\d|\,]{6}[A-M]
```

I'm no pro at regex though,but I used this site everytime to build my pattern:

[RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/)

Use it like this in your code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(yourPatternAsAString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourInputToMatch);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    // gogogo
}
```